# Как пропустить итерацию в dict?

Tags: python

Прохожусь по словарю через loop. Если встречается слово Привет, я хочу пропустить следующие 2 ключа словаря. Как это сделать?

```
for key, value in enumerate(mydict):
   if value='Привет':
      next(mydict) #что то типа такого
      next(mydict) #
```

Comment: Вы ведь не запускали этот код?

Comment: next() я добавил как псевдокод

Comment: Очень похоже, что тут нужен не словарь вообще

Comment: Ну заведи под это дело флаг-счётчик. "Привет"? тройку в счётчик. В счётчике ноль? обрабатываем, иначе декрементируем счётчик.

Answer (score 2):

```
mydict = {"7": 0, 8:0, 5:"Привет", 9:0}

it = iter(mydict.items())
for key, value in it:
   print(key, value)
   if value == 'Привет':
      next(it, None) #что то типа такого
      next(it, None) #
```

Comment: Это плохой стиль внутри цикла по итератору вызывать `next`, смотрите подробности тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53764256/is-it-safe-to-use-next-within-a-for-loop-in-python

Answer (score 1):

В принципе направление мысли правильное, можно и через итератор при помощи `next()`.

```
d = {1:1,2:2,3:"Привет",4:4,5:5,6:6,7:7,8:8,9:9}
i = iter(d.items())
while True:
    try:
        key, value = next(i)
        print(key, "=", value)
        if value == "Привет":
            next(i) #что то типа такого
            next(i) #
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

```
1 = 1
2 = 2
3 = Привет
6 = 6
7 = 7
8 = 8
9 = 9
```

Answer (score 1):

можно немного с извратом сделать:

```
data = {'key1': 'Привет', 'key2': 'ура', 'key3': 'ура', 'key4': 'слово'}

index_next = 0
for index in enumerate(data.keys()):
    if index[0] < index_next:
        continue

    text = data[index[1]]
    print(text)

    if text == 'Привет':
        print(' -> перепрыгиваем')
        index_next = index[0] + 3
        continue

    index_next = index[0] + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Следующие два пропустить - это включая "Привет" или нет? А сам "Привет" пропускать или нет? Если не включая, то вот, но легко можно адаптировать под другие условия:

```
mydict = dict.fromkeys(['124', 'erwef', 'Привет', 'sfsfwef', 'wefrw', '32rf'])

skip = ()
for i, key in enumerate(mydict):
    if i in skip:
        continue
    if key == 'Привет':
        skip = (i + 1, i + 2)
        continue
    print(key)
```

Вывод:

```
124
erwef
32rf
```

"Привет" и следующие два ключа словаря пропущены.

Comment: Почему `skip` кортеж а не счётчик с декрементом?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Чтобы не мучиться с декрементом потом. Так ведь короче )

Comment: А так: `if i < skip:`,  `skip = i + 3` ?